# Simulation of forest growth and pruning

Tags: java, simulation

I was wondering how I could streamline the following code.  This was the project assigned to us:

> The Canadian Forest Service wants to do a simple simulation of the growth and pruning of forests. Each forest has a name and exactly 10 trees. The trees are planted when they are 1' to 5' tall, and each tree has a individual growth rate of 50%-100% per year. For the simulation new trees are constructed randomly within these bounds. A forest is reaped (by lumberjacks) on demand - all trees above a specifed height are cut down and replaced with new trees.
>
> The user interface to the simulation must allow the user to:
>
> - Display the current forest (with tree heights to 2 decimal places)
> - Discard the current forest and create a new forest
> - Simulate a year's growth in the current forest
> - Reap the current forest of trees over a user specified height, replacing the reaped trees with random new trees.
> - Save the information about the current forest to file (named after the forest)
> - Discard the current forest and load the information about a forest from a file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//initialize variables for Forest object, name, height and other inputs
Forest thisForest = null;
        char userInput = ' ';
        String forestName;
        int height = 0;
        String loadName = null;

        while((userInput != 'x') && (userInput != 'X' )){

            switch (userInput) {

//sets the first prompt      
                case ' ':
                    System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                    userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);

                    break;

//Displays the output but only if the forest exists      
                case 'D':
                case 'd':

                    if(thisForest != null){
                        thisForest.display();
                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No Forrest.\n");
                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'N':
                case 'n':

                    System.out.print("What is the name of the forest: ");
                    forestName = scan.next();
                    thisForest = new Forest(forestName);

                    System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                    userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);

                    break;

                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
//grows the equivalent of a "year".   
                    if(thisForest != null){
                        thisForest.yearGrowth();

                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("No forest exists.\n");
                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'R':
                case 'r':

                    //reaps, but only if the forest exists. Catches possible exceptions.
                    if(thisForest != null){
                        try{
                            System.out.print("What height to reap at :");
                            height = scan.nextInt();
                        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid height\n");

                            System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                            scan.nextLine();
                            userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                            break;
                        } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid height\n");

                            System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                            scan.nextLine();
                            userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                            break;
                        }
//end of try-catch       
                        thisForest.reap(height);

                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        scan.nextLine();
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                        break;
//output if there is no forrest       
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("There is no forest to reap.\n");

                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        scan.nextLine();
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                    break;



                case 'S':
                case 's':
//saves the program      
                    if(thisForest != null){
                        try{
                            Forest.saveForest(thisForest);
                        }catch(IOException e){
                            System.out.println("Cannot save.");
                        }
                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No Forrest exists to save.");
                        System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);

                    }
                    break;

                case 'L':
                case 'l':
// loads the program      
                    try{
                        System.out.print("What is the name of the Forest: ");
                        loadName = scan.next();
                        thisForest = Forest.loadForest(loadName);

                    }catch(IOException e){
                        System.out.println("Cannot load.");
                    }
                    System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                    userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Option.");
                    System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
                    userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
//after x is received and the while loop breaks.
        System.out.println("Goodbye");

    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Forest implements Serializable{

//creates variables and constants
    private final int MAX_NUM_TREES = 10;
    private String name;
    private Tree[] arrayOfTrees;
    int index;
    public Forest(String forestName){

        index = 0;
        name = forestName;
        arrayOfTrees = new Tree[MAX_NUM_TREES];

        for(index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length; index++){

            arrayOfTrees[index] = new Tree();

        }
    }

    public void display(){
// displays the array of trees and the index
        index = 0;

        if(name != null){

            System.out.println(name);
            for(index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length; index ++){
                System.out.printf("%2d   :   %s\n", (index + 1), arrayOfTrees[index]);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No forest.");
        }

    }
   public void yearGrowth(){
//grows each tree in the array
        index = 0;

        for(index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length ; index ++){

            arrayOfTrees[index].grow();
        }

    }
   public void reap(int reapHeight){
        //reaps the trees and prints out the old and new information
        index = 0;


        for(index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length; index++){

            if(arrayOfTrees[index].getHeight() >= reapHeight){

                System.out.println("Cut " + (index+1) + " : " + arrayOfTrees[index] );
                arrayOfTrees[index] = new Tree();
                System.out.println("New " + (index+1) + " : " + arrayOfTrees[index] );

            }
        }

    }
public static void saveForest(Forest forest) throws IOException {
//saves the forest
        String name = forest.getName();
        ObjectOutputStream toStream;

        toStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
        toStream.writeObject(forest);
        toStream.close();
    }

   public static Forest loadForest(String fileName) throws IOException {
//loads the forest
        ObjectInputStream fromStream = null;
        Forest local;

        fromStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        try {
            local = (Forest)fromStream.readObject();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return(null);
        }finally{
            try {
                if (fromStream != null) {
                    fromStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                return(null);
            }
        }
        return(local);
    }
    public String getName(){

        return (name);
    }
}
```

Third Class

````
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tree implements Serializable{

//creates the variables as the
    private double height;
    private double growthRate;
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    final double MIN_HEIGHT = 1;
    final double MIN_GROWTH_RATE = 0.5;
    final double MAX_HEIGHT = 5;
    final double MAX_GROWTH_RATE = 1.0;

    public Tree() {
//creates tree with a height and a growth rate
        Random rand = new Random();

        height = (MIN_HEIGHT + ((Math.random() * (MAX_HEIGHT - MIN_HEIGHT))));
        growthRate = (MIN_GROWTH_RATE + (Math.random() * (MAX_GROWTH_RATE - MIN_GROWTH_RATE)));


    }

    public double grow(){
//tree grows and returns height

        height = height * (1 + growthRate);
        return height;


    }

    public double getHeight(){

        return (height);

    }

    public double getGrowthRate(){

        return (growthRate);

    }

    public String toString(){
//toString formats the output with height and growthrate

        return (String.format("%7.2f (%2d%% pa)", height, ((int)(growthRate * 100))));

    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

In your Forest class I don't like how the `int index;` variable is used. I realize that it's working for you because you always set it to 0 before looping, but local variables are that are scoped to a function is the standard way of doing it.

This

```
    index = 0;


    for(index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length; index++){
```

can be replaced with

```
    for(int index = 0; index < arrayOfTrees.length; index++){
```

That will do the same thing and yet be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc, Javadoc, Javadoc!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
```

I'm not a fan of wildcard imports. You might actually end up with the wrong function being imported. Also any modern IDE will happily manage the imports for you.

---

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`scan` is an action, `scanner` would be a better name.

---

```
Forest thisForest = null;
char userInput = ' ';
String forestName;
int height = 0;
String loadName = null;
```

Either you initialize variables with default values, or you don't, be consistent.

---

```
System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :");
userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

You repeat this all over your code, find a way to do this only once (for example at the start of the `while`).

---

```
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Cannot save.");
}
```

Now that is helpful. If you do not know how to handle exceptions then do a `e.printStackTrace()` or `System.err.println(e.getMessage())`, because then the user at least has a chance to figure out *why* it did not work.

Swallowing and silencing exceptions is only acceptable if you *really* know *why* you want this.

---

```
private final int MAX_NUM_TREES = 10;
```

I know this has been declared in the description, but a better way would be to have the `Forest` accept the number of trees and the growth rate in the constructor and have the constant in the `Main` class. That way your `Forest` class can be easier reused.

---

```
int index;
```

Nice idea to reuse the constantly used `int`. However, I hate to break it to you that is completely unnecessary, actually it is the opposite of helpful because it makes your code more error prone and a little bit harder to read. If you start reading the class you see `index` and wonder why the `Forest` requires to hold an index of itself.

Whether or not the JVM has to allocate *one* integer doesn't matter. More so, as `int` is not an `Object`, neither does its allocation influence garbage collection in away. It is way fucking cheap to allocate an `int`, always. Well, if you have something like a million `int`s or so, we can start talking about having them cached, but not a single one.

---

```
private Tree[] arrayOfTrees;
```

Consider using a `List` instead of an array, as it has more convenience functions and is easier to handle.

You still enforce the limit on the number of trees anyway.

---

```
public Forest(String forestName){
    name = forestName;
```

Normally you'd do this:

```
public Forest(String name){
    this.name = name;
```

Don't try to repeat already available information, for example if you have a class which handles the user-input, don't try to have this chain:

```
org.yourdomain.application.inputhandling.InputHandler.handleInput(InputStream)
```

You constantly repeat yourself and add nothing of value to the names.

org.yourdomain.application.ui.StreamHandler.process(InputStream)

So I know it is part of the "user interface" package, so the class handles the input from a stream, and then it processes the input.

Naming is hard, though, takes a lot of practice to get halfway good at it.

---

```
public void display(){
```

Ideally you would only provide means to get the needed information from `Forest` and the main class would handle displaying it.

That decouples your class from the environment it is being used in.

---

```
if(name != null){
```

What? How or why is this a valid state?

```
public Forest(String name){
    if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The forest must have a name.");
    }
```

---

```
public static void saveForest(Forest forest) throws IOException {
```

Why static? If this would be an instance method, extending classes would have a chance to implement their own logic.

Moreover, this should accept a directory (`null` for current).

---

```
ObjectOutputStream toStream;

toStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
```

Why not directly assign it? Moreover, you should use a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to make sure that the stream is always closed.

Creating filestreams has the potential to leak file handles if they have not been closed.

---

```
return(local);
```

Random parenthesis? `return` is a keyword, not a function.

---

```
final double MIN_HEIGHT = 1;
final double MIN_GROWTH_RATE = 0.5;
final double MAX_HEIGHT = 5;
final double MAX_GROWTH_RATE = 1.0;
```

Ideally these would also be properties handed to the Forest. Consider the following structure:

```
class Forest
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_TREES = 10;
    public static final double DEFAULT_MIN_TREEHEIGHT = 0.5d;
    ...

    public Forest(name) {
        this(name, DEFAULT_MAX_TREES, DEFAULT_MIN_TREEHEIGHT, ...)
    }

    public Forest(name, int maximumTrees, double minTreeHeight) {
        trees.add(new Tree(minTreeHeight, ...)
```

But I like that the `Tree` is responsible for its growing, that gives extending classes a chance to easily change the logic and also gives you the possibility to mix different `Tree` classes in the `Forest`.

```
trees.add(new Tree(...));
trees.add(new SlowGrowingTree(...));
trees.add(new FastGrowingTree(...));
trees.add(new SickTree(...));
```

---

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

As a heads up, please always be aware how the default constructor of a PRNG works! In this case this usage is okay because the default constructor of `Random` tries *very, very* hard to not give you to matching instances *ever*. However, the .NET `Random` class for example is (or at least was for a decade) initialized with the current timestamp in seconds, so if you did this:

```
Random a = new Random();
Random b = new Random();
Random c = new Random();
Random d = new Random();
```

All four instances would return the same numbers.

That's something to keep in mind, always check the documentation if you are safe or not.

---

Overall looks quite nice, good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can toUppercase() your userInput. This will reduce the complexity. No need to check if 'a' or 'A', etc.

You should use an ENUM for userInput. Instaed of

`case 'D':`

you'd have:

`case UserChoice.DISPLAY:`